# Parsing arithmetic expressions

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, expression

I'm studying the dragon book and can't wait to write an expression parser.

In order to deal with negative number input, my lexer reads digits when meet the symbol '-' to return a number token.

"-4+2"
Will get (-4,number) (+,operator) (2,number)

but then I found that it can't do things as easy as "4-2" because

(4,number) (-2,number)
It's a wrong syntax.

One of my solution is doing some pre-processing before evaluating an expression, such as appending a zero if the first token is a minus.
I'm wondering how you guys deal with this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Lex it as `(-,operator), (4,number), (+operator), (2,number)` and decide whether the `-` is unary minus or binary subtraction later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my lexer reads digits when meet the symbol '-' to return a negative number

Don't. Unary operators should be dealt with by the parser, not the lexer.

> One of my solution is doing some pre-processing before evaluating an expression, such as appending a zero if the first token is a minus.

No. Fix the *problem.*

When you're in a hole, stop digging.

Answer (score 3):

You should have the following grammar, but not make `"-" number` into a token.

```
number := DIGIT+

unary := number
unary := "-" unary

expr := expr "+" unary
expr := expr "-" unary
...
```

As there are unary expressions, it is not a operator-precedence grammar. You should parse it with a more complex parser.

Comment: Note that this grammar is not complete. It is missing 'term' and 'factor' and 'primary'.